# Inequalities in the context of stability analysis

Tags: inequalities

I find for the study of the active control of a system with 2 dofs to study the stability conditions. 
For that purpose, i use the Routh criteria and look when all the coefficients of the first row are positive.
Here you can find my RouthFirstRow

```
RouthFirstRow = {ma meq + ma α + meq α, ca ma + ceq ma + ca meq + ceq α + ma β + meq β, (ca^2 ceq (ma + meq) + 
  ceq^2 (ma + α) β + ceq (ka ma^2 + keq (ma + α)^2 + ma β^2 + meq β^2 + ma^2 γ) + 
  ca (keq ma^2 + ka (ma + meq)^2 + ceq^2 (ma + α) + 
     2 ceq (ma + meq) β + ma^2 γ + 
     2 ma meq γ + meq^2 γ) + β (keq ma^2 + 
     ka (ma + meq)^2 + (ma + meq)^2 γ))/(ca (ma + meq) + 
  ceq (ma + α) + (ma + meq) β), (ca^3 ceq keq (ma + 
     meq) + keq^2 ma^2 β^2 + 
  ceq^3 (ma + α) β (ka + γ) + 
  ceq^2 (ka^2 ma^2 + 
     keq (ma + α) β^2 + γ (ma β^2 + 
        meq β^2 + ma^2 γ) + 
     ka (ma β^2 + meq β^2 + 2 ma^2 γ)) + 
  ca^2 (keq^2 ma^2 + 3 ceq keq (ma + meq) β + 
     ceq^2 (ka (ma + meq) + 
        keq (ma + α) + (ma + meq) γ)) + 
  ceq β (ka^2 (ma + meq)^2 + 
     keq^2 (ma + α)^2 + (ma + meq)^2 γ^2 - 
     2 ka (keq meq α + 
        keq ma (meq + α) - (ma + meq)^2 γ) + 
     keq meq (β^2 - 2 α γ) + 
     keq ma (β^2 - 2 (meq + α) γ)) + 
  ca (2 keq^2 ma^2 β + 
     ceq^3 (ma + α) (ka + γ) + 
     2 ceq^2 β (ka (ma + meq) + 
        keq (ma + α) + (ma + meq) γ) + 
     ceq (ka^2 (ma + meq)^2 + 
        keq^2 (ma + α)^2 + (ma + meq)^2 γ^2 - 
        2 ka (keq meq α + 
           keq ma (meq + α) - (ma + meq)^2 γ) + 
        keq (3 ma β^2 - 2 ma (meq + α) γ + 
           meq (3 β^2 - 
              2 α γ)))))/(ca^2 ceq (ma + meq) + 
  ceq^2 (ma + α) β + 
  ceq (ka ma^2 + keq (ma + α)^2 + ma β^2 + 
     meq β^2 + ma^2 γ) + 
  ca (keq ma^2 + ka (ma + meq)^2 + ceq^2 (ma + α) + 
     2 ceq (ma + meq) β + ma^2 γ + 
     2 ma meq γ + meq^2 γ) + β (keq ma^2 + 
     ka (ma + meq)^2 + (ma + meq)^2 γ)), keq (ka + γ)};
```

I try to use his syntax to find my conditions but Mathematica thinks about it for a long time butnever gives a result.

```
    Solve[Apply[And, Join[Map[# > 0 &, RouthFirstRow], {meq > 0, ceq > 0, keq > 0, ma > 0, ca > 0, ka > 0}]], {α, β, γ},Reals]
```

Here the results that i would like to obtain :

[image]

Comment: sorry for the bad typesetting, can you help me to correct the grec letters in the code given ? thank you

Comment: I've had a go at cleaning the format.  I hope I've not changed the code.

Comment: Might instead solve for the zero set rather than positive set; this might be faster.